# Google Sheet Subquery of COVID-19 data

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a Google Sheet Query that takes COVID-19 data from [this source](https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data/dataset/covid-19-coronavirus-data) as CSV.

I can successfully import the CSV as a sheet.

I want to make a subquery to get the current day number of each date, that is, in every row, get the first date on each Country, and get the difference.

I also want to subquery the cumulative cases and deaths for each row.

I tried the following query to get the cases and cumulative cases:

```
select G, A, E, (select sum(E) where G=G and A<A)
```

The columns are:

G: Country or territory

A: Date

E: Cases

I get error on the query.

Is there a way to make this kind of subquery in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with QUERY, but you can manage to do it with 3 formulas. Sheet will be automatically updated. Cell A1 contains the IMPORTDATA step.

Number of days :

```
=NB.SI(G2:INDIRECT("G$"&NBVAL($G$1:$G$50000));G2)
```

Total cases :

```
=SOMME(E2:INDIRECT("E"&LIGNE(E2)+K2-1))
```

Total deaths :

```
=SOMME(F2:INDIRECT("F"&LIGNE(F2)+K2-1))
```

[image: Covid]

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eQE-Lo8XkJgyGyxssKCY6pJiGP_sWVoce1wEqFttFX0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The formulas requires after each import to be modified writing the first row of each country. I hoped the process to be automated. I guess I will have to write a custom function.

Comment: Could you develop this part : "writing the first row of each country" ? The sheet is already automated. What do you want to do more ? Please provide an example or more details on your objective.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the formulas to get the first date when a case was reported.

I Imported the data in a sheet called COVID-19. The columns letters are the same as in the question asked.

To get the first date I wrote this formula:

```
=minifs(A:A;G:G;G2;E:E;">0")
```

Then I got the difference with the row's date to get how many days from the row's date to the fist date. I added 1 to have day 1 the first date.

For the number of cases I wrote this formula:

```
=sumifs(E:E;G:G;G2;A:A;"<="&A2)
```

Being the column F the number of deaths the formula is:

```
=sumifs(F:F;G:G;G2;A:A;"<="&A2)
```